# stuck in fingerprint authentication

Tags: login, 22.04, fingerprint-reader

I have updated my Thinkpad T490 laptop to Ubuntu 22.04. Everything went fine.
After the update I have activated the fingerprint to login and... I can not login anymore.
When I click on my user name on the login screen, I briefly (less than 0.5 sec) see the place where I should be able to write my password. I can read the error message "Sorry, fingerprint authentication did not work. Please try again"and then it goes back to the login screen with the name of my user.
I can still access to a terminal using Ctrl + Alt + F5.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?
Is there a way to disable fingerprint authentication from command line?

Comment: You should try until the password field shows up again.

Comment: As workaround you can remove the fingerprint service by `sudo apt remove fprintd` (after log-in into the TTY - Ctrl + Alt + F5), but it will be nice if someone can tell how to get it operational.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The password field was showing each time that I was clicking on my user name, but was disappearing really fast. Sometime I was not even able to see the password field

Comment: @pa4080 Thank you so much, it worked :-D. I was so stressed not to be able to disable the fingerprint. If you write your comment as an answer I will select it as the solution to my problem.

Comment: Retrying "until password login comes up" didn't work for me after 30x tries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having the same problem on my ThinkPad X230T. The workaround is to remove the fingerprint service. So after log-in into a TTY (Ctrl + Alt + F3-F5) you can do that by the command:

```
sudo apt remove fprintd
```

Disabling and stopping the service didn't solve the problem in my case because a few reboots later for some reason it was enabled again.

I haven't investigated yet why it doesn't work as it is expected.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on my HP Envy, and found that I needed to install libpam-fprintd. Try installing `libpam-fprintd` and rebooting; if that doesn't work, remove `fprintd` as pa480 stated, reboot and login, then run

```
sudo apt-get install fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

Your fingerprints should still be saved, and you should be able to logout and use them to log back in; however, I recommend using `fprintd-verify -f ‹finger›` to test your fingerprints before logging out — I've found that I can't get my right index finger to work, but my middle finger works well.

Update: I got my right index finger to work by [resetting my fingerprint reader in the BIOS](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint/-/issues/1).

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating with password is a fallback for failed fingerprint login.

So, if you try (and fail) enough times with the fingerprint the password field will come up eventually.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `fprintd` wasn't installed during the Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade (from 20.04).

I ran `sudo apt-get install fprintd` and restarted. That fixed the issue and I was able to login via password.

(I'm on a Thinkpad T480s)